# Redirect to a function in another admin controller from one admin controller in magento

Tags: magento, redirect, module, controller

I have to call a function from one controller to another controller.

I need to call a function from testAction() in testController to indexAction() in anotherController.

How could i call that one. I tried below ones. but that doesn't seems to work. Please advice me.

```
$this->_redirect("./admin/another/index", array("group_id" => $group_id));

$this->_forward($action = 'indexAction', $controller = 'adminhtml_another', $module = 'custommodule');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. now redirection working fine. i have just add below `'return;'` statement. the code is,

```
$this->_redirect("adminhtml/newsletter_template/"); 
return;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are redirecting from one controller to another

```
$this->_redirect('customer/account/login'); 
//Format: $this->_redirect('module/controller/action');
```

If in the same controller

```
//$this->_redirect('*/*/SameControllerMethodAction');
```

UPDATED:
Your solution :

```
$this->_redirect('adminhtml/newsletter_template/index');
```

with

```
Adminhtml - module
Newsletter (Folder) > Template - controller
Index - function
```

Comment: acually i need to redirect to newsletter index action. i tried with "$this->_redirect("newsletter/template/index");" but it does not work.

Comment: Make sure that you have template controller in Newsletter Module. Btw, there is no template controller by default in Magento. Btw what are you getting 404 not found? or redirect?

Comment: Its not 'newsletter/template/index', just 'adminhtml/newsletter_template/index'.

Comment: @anz it's working fine $this->_redirect('adminhtml/newsletter_template/index'); But We need to redirect to new page. How to possible this case.